# Retrieve form is not filled selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces, converters, selectonemenu

I'm newbie using JSF and primefaces.
I have a form containing 3 selectOneMenus which are filled from three converters respectively.

When saving data it is saved fine, but when on the same form to recover not shown selectOneMenu elements. Although the objects relate if loaded correctly.

CONVERTER

```
@FacesConverter(value = "auxiliarConvertir")
public class AuxiliarConvertir implements Converter {

    public static AuxiliarDao auxiliarDAO = new AuxiliarDaoImpl();
    private AuxiliarMB auxiliarMB;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component,
            String submittedValue) {
        if (submittedValue.trim().equals("")) {
            return null;
        } else {
            try {
                auxiliarMB = (AuxiliarMB) facesContext
                        .getELContext()
                        .getELResolver()
                        .getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null,
                                "auxiliarBean");

                List<Auxiliar> listaAuxiliar = auxiliarMB.getTabla();
                String number = submittedValue;
                for (Auxiliar p : listaAuxiliar) {
                    if (p.getAuxiliarCodigo().equals(number)) {
                        return p;
                    }
                }

            } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(
                        FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error",
                        "Not a valid player"));
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component,
            Object value) {
        if (value == null || value.equals("")) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return String.valueOf(((Auxiliar) value).getAuxiliarCodigo());
        }
    }

}
```

XHTML

```
<p:column colspan="2">
    <p:selectOneMenu id="auxiliares"
        value="#{comprasBean.auxiliar}" converter="auxiliarConvertir"
        panelStyle="width:550px" effect="fade" var="p"
        style="width:95px" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith">
        <p:ajax update="razonSocial" listener="#{comprasBean.pinta}" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Elija" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{auxiliarBean.tabla}" var="auxi"
            itemLabel="#{auxi.auxiliarCodigo}" itemValue="#{auxi}" />
        <p:column>
             #{p.auxiliarCodTribut}
        </p:column>
        <p:column> 
             #{p.auxiliarRazonSocial} #{p.auxiliarApellidoP} #{p.auxiliarApellidoM} #{p.auxiliarNombre1}
        </p:column>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:column>
```

Please if you need other information tell me.
Thank you for using your time to help others.

Comment: The first problem: you cannot nest `p:columns` inside a `p:selectOneMenu` - I'm not eve sure what that'd be supposed to look like. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your interest to have these <p:column> serve within a table like the image

https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/253341_10200927646304378_938745139_n.jpg

Comment: What problem do you have? Exception? Components not rendered?

Comment: When retrieving data from the database does not update selectOneMenu, I think it's by the converter, since these are related objects.

Comment: and the problem is not to keep it, since I keep, and also recovering well but it does not put in the selectOneMenu